# Remove duplicates while merging lists of lists into single list in python

Tags: python

So, I have lists of lists like following:

```
data = [
['foo', 'bar'],
['one', 'two']
]
```

And, I want to flatten these lists by alternating between two lists.
So, output like

```
flattened = ['foo', 'one', 'bar', 'two']
```

I am using the `list(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(*data)))`
which works fine.

But, I am trying to figure out how to handle scenarios where there are duplicates that I want to get rid of.

```
data = [
['foo', 'bar'],
['foo', 'two']
]
```

I want something like

```
flatted = ['foo', 'two', 'bar']
```

rather than `['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'two']`

How do I do this?

Comment: does order matter?

Comment: @Marat, well if they want to alternate between lists, then inherently yes.

Comment: @Marat: yeah...

Comment: I don't have time at the moment but you can implement an [ordereddict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from your output list and then convert back or dict in 3.7+

Comment: The correct output is `['foo', 'bar', 'bar'] `or `['foo', 'two', 'bar']`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a set to keep track of what you've already seen, which is an O(1) membership test.

```
result = []
seen = set()
for item in chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(*data)):
    if item not in seen:
        seen.add(item)
        result.append(item)
>>> result
['foo', 'bar', 'two']
```

Note that this question talks about removing duplicates from a list: [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

**TL;DR**

For Python 3.7+ (or Cython 3.6+):

```
>>> list(dict.fromkeys(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(*data))))
['foo', 'bar', 'two']
```

Comment: OP is requesting `['foo', 'two', 'bar'] `, not `['foo', 'bar', 'two'] `

Comment: "something like" `['foo', 'two', 'bar']`

Comment: yes I thought that initially as well but technically only 1 of those lists satisfies the values "alternating between two lists" as OP specified earlier. It's ambiguous at the end of the day so who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
list(dict.fromkeys(sum(data, [])))
```

**EDIT:**
As pointed out in the comments, the `sum` is not the most efficient method to flatten a list, you can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to get the flattened list, then do the following:

```
list(dict.fromkeys(chain.from_iterable(data)))
```

In both cases the output is the following:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'two']
```

### Comparison of execution times

Below they propose a comparison of the execution times of the main proposed solutions:

1. Benchmark data1:

   ```
    data1 = [['foo', 'bar'],['foo', 'two']] * 1000000
   ```

   1. #### [@Massifox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58069082/9302488)'s solution with `itertools.chain.from_iterable`

      ```
      %%timeit
      list(chain.from_iterable(data1))
      # 128 ms ± 11.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
      ```
   2. #### [@Marat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58069188/9302488)'s solution with `dedup`

      ```
      %%timeit
      list(dedup(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(*data1))))
      # 579 ms ± 116 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
      ```
   3. #### [@Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58069144/9302488)'s solution with `zip_longest`

      ```
      %%timeit
      list(dict.fromkeys(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(*data1))))
      # 456 ms ± 149 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
      ```
2. Benchmark data2:

   ```
   x = 10
   y = 500000
   n_max = 1000
   data2 = [[np.random.randint(1, n_max) for _ in range(0, x)] for _ in range(0, y)]
   ```

   1. #### [@Massifox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58069082/9302488)'s solution with `itertools.chain.from_iterable`

      ```
      %%timeit
      list(chain.from_iterable(data2))
      # 241 ms ± 20 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
      ```
   2. #### [@Marat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58069188/9302488)'s solution with `dedup`

      ```
      %%timeit
      list(dedup(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(*data2))))
      # 706 ms ± 18.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
      ```
   3. #### [@Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58069144/9302488)'s solution with `zip_longest`

      ```
      %%timeit
      list(dict.fromkeys(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(*data2))))
      # 674 ms ± 56.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
      ```

The implementations based on `sum` and on `Counter` are
    decisively less efficient and take tens of seconds already with
    instances of smaller benchmark of `[['foo', 'bar'],['foo', 'two']] * 100k`.

**With benchmark `data1`**, the solution based on `itertools.chain.from_iterable` proposed by me seems to be about 4-5 times faster than the others.

**With benchmark `data2`**, the solution based on `itertools.chain.from_iterable` proposed by me seems to be about 2-3 times faster than the others.

Comment: This is pretty good but `sum` is a terribly slow way to flatten a list.

Comment: This produces "bar" before it produces "two", OP is requesting that the opposite happens.

Comment: @BrianJoseph Probably the author of the post was wrong to expect that output, I'm asking for confirmation in the comments

Comment: These timings tests are _so_ wrong... You have four million data points, but only three of which are unique.  Furthermore, your timed solution gives the wrong result.

Comment: are correct on my machine on that benchmark instance.  If you have another instance to offer, write it in the comments that the text and add it to the comparison. Thanks

Comment: @Alexander I updated my answer and added another benchmark instance with different features. I added the results. Let me know what you think. Thanks

Comment: Better representation of the data, but your answer still gives the wrong result because it contains duplicates which still need to be removed.

Comment: @Alexander, I updated the execution times of your solution, by mistake I still used the first instance instead of the second one. Why do you say the results are different? sorted (your_sol) == sorted (my_sol)  gives True.

Comment: Per your `timeit` function above, your result gives the wrong answer. `>>> list(chain.from_iterable(data))  # ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'two']`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this might be a bit more overhead than you're looking for but this *should* work and guarantees list-wise order unlike sets:

```
from itertools import cycle
from collections import Counter

output = []
checker = Counter()

for lst in cycle(data):
    if not data:
        break

    while lst:
        item = lst.pop(0)
        if not checker[item]:
            output.append(item)
            checker[item] += 1
            break            

    if not lst:
        data.remove(lst)
        continue
```

output:

```
['foo', 'two', 'bar']
```

Answer (score -3):

you can create a set and then convert to list again some like this:

```py
l1 = ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'two']
l2 = list(set(l1))
```

it's create a second list without repeated items

if you want keept the order you can do this

```py
ordered = dict.fromkeys(l1).keys()
```

Comment: Will this always maintain order?

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb Sets are unordered but you can probs find a OrderedSet datatype somewhere.

Comment: Agree @JoshuaNixon which was my point. Dict does in 3.7+ based on insertion order.

Comment: so, you can use same example using ordereddict instance of dict